# PHP: skip code on any error

Tags: php

I have written a supersimple code to track my blog's activity.
I'm including this file on every page at the very begining:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["i"] == "") {
  $_SESSION["i"] = rand(0,9) . chr(rand(65,90)) . chr(rand(65,90)) . chr(rand(65,90));
}

  $r = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  if ($r == "") {$r = "Direct";}
  $u = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db.php');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO analytika (id, page, referrer, visit, time) VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, DEFAULT)");
  $stmt->bind_param("sss",$u,$r,$_SESSION["i"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
?>
```

Problem is, what do I do to prevent echo's from PHP when error occures?
I've found `error_reporting(0);` but that obviously isn't the solution, because my page wont load further the error. And since im including things into DB, problems may really occur.

So, how do I rewrite my code to skip itself if something goes wrong and the page loads on as it would normally? Thanks
PHP 7.0

Comment: You should fix the errors, not skip them. What is the error message you get?

Comment: @KirkBeard There are none now, it works just fine. Im just worried about some random error in future breaking the site. The text content is what the blog is about, so if for some reason this php tracking wont fire&log, i dont really care.

Comment: You could simply probe for DB connectivity here, but if that were to fail, your page would eventually be down anyway. Why not use a tracker ?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a try/catch block to handle errors that you think may occur e.g. "what do you want to happen if your database is unavailable?"
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

In PHP you can suppress error messages using the `@` operator. Again though it's recommended that you handle errors. This wouldn't prevent an error in your script from stopping execution.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

When you're using PHP in production, it's highly recommended not to show exceptions and errors, and even notices and warnings. To prevent showing these bad characters, you have to change `display_errors` option in php.ini file (see the link for more details).

However, there's another option. For instance, if you could not change ini file, you can use `ini_set()` function on every page you want to disable error reporting. But there is a problem with `ini_set()`; from php.net:

> Note: Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.

Also, to track errors, you can set `log_errors` and `error_log` options, by changing php.ini or using ini_set() function.